# NoMethodError (undefined method 'active?' for <User:...>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nomethoderror

I"m using Ruby on Rails 3.0.4 / Devise 1.4.2 / MySQL / Apache/Passenger / FreeBSD

The problem occurs on user sign up at email confirmation page. At the same time, confirmation email is sent to the new user and if you click on the confirmation link, the confirmation and user sign in work fine.

models/user.rb:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :trackable, :recoverable, :confirmable, :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable
```

What could it be? Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: `active?` method works only for Devise version less than 1.4, and for versions newer than 1.3 `confirmed?` should be used.

I generated Devise scripts with Devise 1.1.7, then upgraded to 1.4.2 - and the problem appeared. I downgraded to 1.3.0 and that was the cure.

Answer (score 1):

Devise as far as I know does not ship with `active?` method. Please try to use `confirmed?` instead, as long as you have `Confirmable` module included.

Comment: I changed `active?` to `confirmable?` and now the app doesn't throws an error, but simply redirects back to sign in page with notice 'you must log in' which means that the requested page (email confirmation text page) needs authorisation.

Comment: You should change it to `confirmed?` not `confirmable?`. And a here is a tip: method used to confirm user is `confirm!` if I recall correctly(check docs to be sure). So you can play with user in console while making clicks as your user in the browser window.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in my comment. I changed to `confirmed?`, as you suggested - it works (no error at least) but the app behavior is wrong. I'm trying to degrade Devise version (as this code worked before).

Comment: yeah, the suspicion was right... I downgraded to 1.3.0 - and `active?` method was recognized by Devise

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Devise, but it sounds likely that Devise expects the users table to have a boolean "active" attribute. If it had, Rails would generate the `active?` method.

Comment: I've already checked that... Nope, it seems that the issue is not about the field. There is no such field on dev env and it works fine.